# two inequalities of four real numbers

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c,d$ are four positive real numbers, then show that
   $$\frac{12}{(a+b+c+d)} \leq { \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{a+c} + \frac{1}{a+d} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{b+d} + \frac{1}{c+d}} \leq \frac34 \left[\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d}\right]$$

Comment: sorry now i corrected the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{4}{x+y}\leq \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ for $x\gt0$ and $y\gt0$ 
To prove the hint, notice it's equivalent to $\frac{4}{x+y}\leq \frac{x+y}{xy}$, cross multiply(you can do it because both $x$ and $y$ are positive) to get the equivalent inequality $(x+y)^2\geq4xy$, which is proved in the comment.

Back to original question, for the first one, use the hint
$\frac{4}{a+b+c+d}\leq\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{c+d}$, write down the other two similiar inequalities, add them together. For the second one $\frac{4}{a+b}\leq\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$, write down similar inequalities and add them together.

Comment: By arithmetic-harmonic mean. Though, to be precise, we should restrict $x,y$ to being strictly positive.

Comment: OK I've edited it.

Comment: how did you get the inequality by AM-HM mean

Comment: $(x+y)^2-4xy=(x-y)^2\geq 0$ so $(x+y)^2\geq4xy$ which is equivalent to the hint.

Comment: what to do next and how to prove second inequality

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula The hint is useful for both inequalities

Comment: if you don't mind can you give the full solution as i have to submit tomorrow

Comment: I've edited it.